# How to change x-label in plot without showing the previous values?

Tags: r, plot

I'm tryng to plot with `plot` the following:

```
df = (DF = c(24, 62, 37, 27, 50, 20, 23, 23, 25, 20, 27, 25, 24, 11, 23, 21, 17, 20, 17, 13, 13, 13, 15, 15, 14, 10))

plot(df$DF, type = "o", col = "red", lwd = 2, xlab = "", ylab = "Growth Rate (%)")
```

The problem is that I get on the x-axis numbers from 1 to 27.

I would like to have days there from Feb 25 to March 22. So, I tried:

```
df$Date <- seq(as.Date("2020/02/25"), as.Date("2020/03/22"), by = "days")

plot(df$DF, type = "o", col = "red", lwd = 2, xlab = "", ylab = "Growth Rate (%)") + axis(1, at=1:27, labels= df$Date, cex.axis=0.5)
```

The problem is that the new x-label is written on the old one.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You want to plot DF by Date? Simply use `plot(df$Date, df$DF, type = "o", col = "red", lwd = 2, xlab = "", ylab = "Growth Rate (%)", cex.axis=0.5)`?

Comment: @stefan I tried this before. It works well. The problem (I didn't mention) is that when I use your solution, if I try to add an additional line (`lines()`), it is no longer displayed. Any idea why and how to add a line even under your solution?

Comment: Just tried adding a line with some random numbers. Worked. Maybe you have to adjust the scale of the axis? At least for my example some values did not show up. However, I have to admit that I'm just a beginner with base R plotting. Do all my stuff with ggplot2. (;

Comment: @stefan very curious... It's not a problem of scale. It doesn't work in my case, mah. I also use ggplot2. I thought to use plot this time to be quicker and instead... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create the data
df = data.frame(DF = c(24, 62, 37, 27, 50, 20, 23, 23, 25, 20, 27, 25, 24, 11, 23, 21, 17, 20, 17, 13, 13, 13, 15, 15, 14, 10))

df$Date <- seq(as.Date("2020/02/25"), as.Date("2020/03/21"), by = "day")
df$data_line <- c(24, 62, 37, 27, 50, 20, 23, 23, 25, 20, 27, 25, 24, 11, 23, 21, 17, 20, 17, 13, 13, 13, 15, 15, 14, 10) + 2

# Open the plot area 
     plot(df$Date, df$DF, 
     type = "o", col = "red", lwd = 2, xlab = "",ylab = "Growth Rate (%)", axes = F)

     # Configuring the new axes
     axis.Date(1, at = seq(min(df$Date), max(df$Date), by ="day"), cex.axis= 0.5)
     axis(2, las = 2)

     # Add a new line     
     lines(df$Date, df$data_line, col = "blue")

     # Close the box around the plot area
     box()
```

Hi Rollo,

In base r plot, I prefer to insert each thing separately. I recreated your data example and plot the data again. I plotted a blue line with a new example of data, created by adding 2 to the original DF data, it was stored in df$data_line.

When I called the plot, I used the argument 'axes = F', to omit the original axes. After this I called the two axes, with different functions.

In r base plot you can't use "+" between functions when you open a plot.

Hope my code helps you!

Comment: This is really good Leonardo. Thanks a lot for your nice solution and hint!